# Efficient implementation for performing word count

Tags: mysql, oracle

I'd like to ask you for some advice on my research for my thesis.

I am building an application, where I'll have 1000 articles of 200-300 words and then a "word frequency list" - 30.000 words, each one rated according to usage across an English corpora e.g. "of" - 20168 times, "the" - 6464684 times, "aquaintance" - 15 times and so forth....

Now I want to query the database with lists of words and I want an article returned that contains most of these words, the most times.

```
E.g.: my list: different, contemporary, persistency.
Article 1 contains contemporary 1x
article 2 contains contemporary 3x
So the returned article would be no 2.
```

Questions

1. Should I create any relations among words and articles in the database. I mean for a thousand articles each one 300 words (well not unique) that would be quite a list. Or would an index suffice?
2. Mysql vs Oracle? With Mysql I'd use SOLR to index, I know that oracle has a tool for indexing but nothing more about it.
3. Is oracle with such functionality available for free? And also is it easy to handle, because I've never worked with it, but if the setup would be easy, I would go for it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The sizes you are talking about shouldn't have any issue running on the free Oracle XE database or on a mysql database. Do you already have the list of rated words? What happens if the article has a word which isn't in your rated list?

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, I do have the list. If the word isn't there, then it should return nothing.
Does Oracle come with any indexing for such purpose?

Answer (score 3):

I will recommend you to use Hadoop to perform a WordCount operation. This will be scalable later (you're a researcher!)  and efficient. Moreover creating relations among words, and articles in the database doesn't look like a neat solution.

If you choose Hadoop, it will provide the functionality of MapReduce. It works like this:

- divides all input text files amongst multiple physical machines
- each machine performs the word count algorithm
- Results are collected from all machines, and then combined to give the final output.

You don't have to worry about implementing these functionalities, here is a [tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3a+WordCount+v1.0).

WordCount job can also run locally on one machine.

Comment: Looks good, but does it have any index? Where are the results stored? Because I need those results in a reasonable time (like a few seconds)

Comment: The results will be stored in a flat file.